# Implementation approach for a RESTFUL EJS template service?

Tags: node.js, rest, ejs

Imagine a service that already has a full ecommerce catalog and purchasing etc back office with a RESTFUL API that developers can use to connect to remotely to create ecommerce websites from it. I have already built this. What I was hoping for is some advice in implementing a RESTFUL EJS service on top of this that would allow for a developer to specify an EJS template file via http resource URL and a typical catalog query in the same call such as:

```
http://mywebsite.ecommerceapi.com/catalogid/products?query=sunglasses&ejs=httpurl
```

The resulting service would then return the rendered EJS template (using caching etc for the query and EJS template). This would be primarily for SEO purposes and allowing the developers to create the same solution client-side in terms of templating as they do in server-side so it eases development in simplifying how client-side and server-side templates are done regardless of the technology used to setup the websites.

Your suggestions? I also have no problem with you saying "this is a bad idea" but please give reasons.

Comment: So you are asking for suggestions regarding what? I'd say "your idea is ok" or "yes, you can do that, go ahead". The url query is easy to interpret and handle, what exactly do you want to implement in NodeJS? If you already have a working service, where would NodeJS come in?

Comment: I'm unsure of the security issues and suggested measures to make this a safe thing as its on a multi-tenant environment. Is this something that can be quickly setup in terms of node parsing an EJS template given its a URL resource pulled in on the fly while also making it secure? Is there any code samples you could provide, however small?